# Apply Box Shadow for Select inside P tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, webkit

I want to add css3 box shadow for a select box. It works in all browsers except Google chrome. Since I am wrapping form elements by p tags I can't wrap select tags by div tags (Since div inside p is not allowed in HTML). Is there any other way to apply box shadow for select boxes in Google chrome?

HTML page

```
<form method="post">
 <p>
   <label for"option_box"">Title:</label>

    <select name="option_box">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>

 </p>
```

CSS

```
select {
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add following lines to css file

```
.shadow_select {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.shadow_select:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

2) Then apply shadow_select class for select tags

```
<select class="shadow_slect">
     <option>AAAAA</option>
     <option>BBBBB</option>
     <option>CCCCC</option> 
</select>
```

This works on all other browsers except webkit. for webkit wrap select using div. Then use jquery to detect focus event on select and apply CSS shadow class to that div. (Because focus event can't be applied to a div)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap it using a span element and then you can apply the style to that span element

HTML page

```
<span class="select">    
    <select name="option_box">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

CSS

```
span.select {
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
}
```

Comment: Is the form located into a table? I mean tabe > tr > td ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this website - http://jsfiddle.net/UD2QP/134/

They have a working solution, that I was able to use on the latest Chrome. (I would have commented above, but I can't yet. :)

Good luck!

Comment: ya bt since I am already wrapping form controls insed p tags I can't wrap them using div tags. since div inside p is not allowed.

Comment: You can do that trick with p tags. Try it in the demo. I changed the code in the boxes to use p tags instead of divs. The idea is to put the box-shadow on the containing elements, in your case p tags.

Comment: Actually, just throw another p tag around the select, and give it the box-shadow if you can't refactor your markup.